Organize values in a list format
I know how to do sorting using the command sort.Ints, but the values are shown like this:
[1,2,3,4...]

I would like to organize these values into a list, like this:
1
2
3
4...

Which command should I use to get this result?

Are you asking how to print the numbers in your slice?

Apparently you're confusing abstract data structures with printing them (for being viewed by a user).

Maybe you're looking for something like this?
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    arr := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    for _, number := range arr {
        fmt.Println(number)
    }
}


Exactly! Thank you very much!
